# Rails: Handling data not found from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rails-activerecord

This is probably one of the most basic questions out there but I still thought stackoverflow would be the best way for me to get the logic right.

My simple question is, how do you handle the database query if it does not return anything. Here is my code below;

```
@tokenSelected=Token.where(:tokenCode => "ABCDRRREF").first
```

And later on when I want to check if the @userSelected.userID is empty, it gives me the error;

```
<h1>
  NoMethodError
    in InitsController#create
</h1>
<pre>undefined method `empty?&#x27; for nil:NilClass</pre>
```

What can I do to prevent that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `empty?` use [`blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F)

```
   @tokenSelected.blank?
```

An object is blank if it’s false, empty, or a whitespace string. For example, “”, “ ”, nil, [], and {} are all blank.

Comment: `object.present? == !object.blank?`. Use either which fits.

Answer (score 2):

Use `object.present?` it returns `false` for nil, [], {}, empty string and empty collection.